# Vulkan normalized value formula (eg VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM)?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan a format such as `VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` maps a single-precision float in the range `[0.0f,1.0f]` to an 8-bit unsigned integer.  Is the formula for the float->uint8_t direction **exactly**:

```
uint8_t unorm(float x) {
  return roundf(x*255.0f);
}
```

where round is the standard C function? or is it something else? or is it implementation-defined?

(Note that the above would give half as many values to uint8_t(0) and uint8_t(255) as it would to the other values uint8_t(1), uint8_t(2) through uint8_t(254).)

Comment: The standard [spells this out pretty clearly](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap4.html#fundamentals-fixedconv). Or at least, as clearly as it can while still letting the exact mechanism be implementation-defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks, that is what I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 3.9.2. Conversion from Floating-Point to Normalized Fixed-Point

> The conversion from a floating-point value f to the corresponding unsigned normalized fixed-point value c is defined by first clamping f to the range [0,1], then computing
>
> c = convertFloatToUint(f × (2b - 1), b)
>
> where convertFloatToUint(r,b) returns one of the two unsigned binary integer values with exactly b bits which are closest to the floating-point value r. Implementations should round to nearest. If r is equal to an integer, then that integer value must be returned. In particular, if f is equal to 0.0 or 1.0, then c must be assigned 0 or 2b - 1, respectively.